# How to stop rsync from canceling when encountering a symlink without a referent

Tags: rsync

I use rsync to backup home dir of my computer 1 to computer 2 like this:

```
rsync --recursive --archive --copy-unsafe-links --hard-links \
      --delete-after --fuzzy --compress --human-readable \
      --quiet --delete-excluded \
  --exclude mail \
  --exclude .ssh \
  --exclude .wine \
  --exclude .byobu/.ssh-agent \
  --exclude .config/pulse/*-runtime \
  \ # some more excludes go here
  /home/myusername/ \
  computer2hostname:/mnt/storrrage/computer1_backup/
```

Some programs like pulseaudio create bad symlinks on my computer regularly. So, when it finds a bad symlink, it does this:

```
symlink has no referent: "/home/myusername/.kde/tmp-computer1"
symlink has no referent: "/home/myusername/.kde/socket-computer1"
```

How can I make rsync proceed even after encountering a bad symlink, just don't copy it or copy it, whatever, I don't care? Just log it and don't cancel the backup. (by cancelling I mean `--delete-after` is not performed, and maybe files are not copied, not sure.

Comment: Can you try using with syntax of `rsync --recursive --archive --copy-links --copy-unsafe-links --hard-links` in the first line of the command? So just include the `--copy-links` parameter too but preferable after the `--archive` parameter as per the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) from what I gathered.

Comment: One more thing for you.... Follow this post: https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2009-July/023532.html and read along each **next message** as the solution in this case was to `chroot` so read about it when you get a chance. I assume these are two simple things you can try at least.